# Is there any way to load images up to display resolution only (instead of full size) - Blogger

Tags: html, css, image

I want to load images in the display resolution only instead of full size/resolution.

here is an Example which will help you understand my issue:
Let a image is of 512x512px (has size 1MB) but while displaying it on webpage i use to resize it's display size to 200x200px using css.

but the image will load(it will still require download of 1MB) in full 512x512px resolution, though it will be rendered to smaller display size of 200x200px due to css.

What i want that image should load in the display size resolution of 200x200px. thus it's size will be reduced (less than 1MB) while loading.

This will decrease the website loading time as well as data transfer and improves the website performance.

**I am using Blogger.**

Comment: You have to do it from server side.! Webpages will get displayed by downloading the contents from the server.

Comment: Images can't just be loaded in a different resolution. It would have to be converted to the other resolution, creating a new image file. It sounds like you are trying to create thumbnails for large images in a gallery or something? Your server needs to create a resized thumbnail image every time an image is uploaded.

Comment: You'll have to create multiple versions of your image and choose the right one with JavaScript. The HTML5 `<picture>` element--which does exactly this--isn't supported by browsers yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a thumbnail version by a server side program in php/.net/...
Its impossible to change the size or resolution on the fly just by plain html. javascript is also need some application (server side) to integrate this.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is no. You need the image on your server to be 200 pixels.

You can do this if you have control over the backend system to resize the images based on passed parameters. http://www.example.com/image?width=200&height=200.

One could possibly think of having a browser that could download only a part of the file using file formats based on wavelet compression like JPEG2000. I don't think browsers support partial downloads of JPEG2000 images.